# Error403 Forbidden when using YouTube analytics Api to extract the data of a channel I am the editor of

Tags: api

Youtube Analytics API Error403 Forbidden as a channel editor

Hi,
I am using YouTube analytics Api to extract a YouTube channel data which I am the editor. I use the confidential of my own account and just define the channel id in the request code. Since I can export and view data on YouTube I thought that would not be an issue. But it ends up showing Error403: Forbidden. I successfully used the api to export my own channel's data even it's 0.
I don't have the channel account information since I only have access to YouTube studio.
Is there anyway to configure or export without involving the channel owner?

Thanks for the support!